# Jupyter - autorun cells on page load

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to hide code blocks in the jupyter notebook.
I had added next cell:

```
%%javascript
$('div.input').hide();
```

How can I run this cell on page load?

Thank U!